# "Insert SQL" by inserting the same value into the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a bidding system that works with a robotic bidding automatic, and also with a button where the customer can bid.

When the client clicks the button, it calls a function that executes the following query:

```
$qryins = "Insert into bid_account (user_id,bidpack_buy_date,bid_count,auction_id,product_id,bid_flag,bidding_price,bidding_type,bidding_time)
                values('$uid',NOW(),'1','$aid','$prid','d',$newprice,'s'," . $oldtime . ")";
```

This query is in a PHP file.

The part of robotic is done by a procedure in the database, with the following command, which runs every second:

```
Insert into bid_account (user_id, bidpack_buy_date, bid_count, auction_id, product_id, bid_flag, bidding_price, bidding_type, bidding_time)
        SELECT prox_user_id, NOW(), '1', auctionID, productID, 'd', prox_valor, 's', auc_due_time FROM t_autolances
        WHERE prox_valor NOT IN (SELECT bidding_price FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id=auctionID);
```

Bids are run with a timer, equal to those auctions of cents. The problem that is occurring is that if the customer clicks the button at the same time that the robo gives the bid, it writes to the database with equal values.

I need it to write the different value to the "**bidding_price**" column, like this:

I need it written this way:

```
robot 0.25
customer 0.26
```

and not like this:

```
robot 0.25
client 0.25
```

I did not want to put all the code here because it is too long, so I put the most important parts.

```
$q = "select * from auc_due_table adt left join auction a on adt.auction_id=a.auctionID left join auction_management am on a.time_duration=am.auc_manage where auction_id=$aid";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
$ob = mysqli_fetch_object($r);

$oldtime = $ob->auc_due_time;
$oldprice = $ob->auc_due_price;
$plusprice = $ob->auc_plus_price;
$plustime = $ob->auc_plus_time;
$newprice = $ob->pennyauction == 1 ? $oldprice + 0.01 : $oldprice + $plusprice;
$newtime = $oldtime < $plustime ? $plustime : $oldtime;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Where does `$newprice` come from? What's supposed to prevent the user from bidding the same price right after the computer has done it?

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question, take a look.

Comment: @Sammitch Do you have any examples of what it would look like in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the addition of the user's amount in SQL, not in PHP.

```
$qryins = "Insert into bid_account (user_id,bidpack_buy_date,bid_count,auction_id,product_id,bid_flag,bidding_price,bidding_type,bidding_time)
            SELECT '$uid', NOW(),'1', auction_id, '$prid','d', 
                    auc_due_price + IF(pennyauction, 0.01, auc_plus_price), 's', auc_due_time
            from auc_due_table adt 
            left join auction a on adt.auction_id=a.auctionID 
            left join auction_management am on a.time_duration=am.auc_manage 
            where auction_id=$aid";
```

The other solution is to use a transaction. Start the transaction before the `SELECT` query, and commit it after the `INSERT`.

```
mysqli_query($db, "START TRANSACTION");
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
$ob = mysqli_fetch_object($r);
$oldtime = $ob->auc_due_time;
$oldprice = $ob->auc_due_price;
$plusprice = $ob->auc_plus_price;
$plustime = $ob->auc_plus_time;
$newprice = $ob->pennyauction == 1 ? $oldprice + 0.01 : $oldprice + $plusprice;
$newtime = $oldtime < $plustime ? $plustime : $oldtime;
$qryins = "...";
mysqli_query($db, $qryins);
mysqli_query($db, "COMMIT");
```

Comment: Can you give me an example using a transaction? I had already researched this function, but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
   Insert 
       into bid_account 
                     (
                     user_id, 
                     bidpack_buy_date, 
                     bid_count, 
                     auction_id, 
                     product_id, 
                     bid_flag, 
                     bidding_price, 
                     bidding_type, 
                     bidding_time
                     )
             SELECT 
                     prox_user_id, 
                     NOW(), 
                     '1', 
                     auctionID, 
                     productID, 
                     'd', 
                     (SELECT max(bidding_price)+0.01 FROM bid_account WHERE auction_id=auctionID) AS bidding_price,                     
                     's', 
                     auc_due_time 
             FROM 
                     t_autolances
             LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I tried that way but it did not work, if the customer bid in the same second as the computer, it inserts the same value.